# How do dependency injection frameworks create new instances?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Since [creating a new instance of a generic type requires its constructor be parameterless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint), I'm wondering how DI frameworks go about creating new instances for you?

Comment: They do not create generics, but only concrete classes - which are requested by you

Comment: They create instances via reflection, not with "new" operator (they can't use new anyway because for its usage you need to know the type at compile time). With reflection you can create instance of any type with any constructor arguments, generic or not.

Comment: Invariably through `Activator.CreateInstance`, or build-time codegen.

Comment: Also, the `new()` constraint in C# is a bit of a code-smell (imo) precisely because any useful type with a parameterless constructors has to be mutable, and mutable types are a pain in the long-term. Instead of using `where T : new()` consider adding a `Func<T> factory` method parameter, which allows your code to delegate object creation to your code's consumer.

Comment: I believe you are misinterpreting that specific C# reference article. The article specifically talks about the `new` generic type constraint. The `new` constraint does *not* force the generic type to have a parameterless constructor, it only forces the type's *generic type argument* to have a parameterless constructor. And even so, the `new` constraint is *completely optional*. It, therefore, doesn't hinder DI Containers -or anyone else creating types using Reflection or code generation- to create a generic type.